# Indexer that points to item in struct array don't work

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have a class called Surface, in this class i have an array of type struct Color.

```
public class Surface
{
    private Color[,] pixels;

    public Color this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return pixels[y, x]; }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Color
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte R;

    public void Set(byte r)
    {
        R = r;
    }
}
```

However when i try to access the color using the indexer it don't get updated.

```
mySurface[x, y].Set(255); // Will not work, i don't get an error but the color don't get updated.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You've just discovered why [mutable structs are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)  Try `var temp = mySurface[x,y]; temp.Set(255); mySurface[x,y] = temp;` instead.

Comment: Other question connected http://stackoverflow.com/q/4720475/613130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i solve this problem?

Well you could avoid creating mutable structs and exposing public fields, to start with. That's where the problem is coming from. Your code is effectively:

```
Color tmp = mySurface[x, y]; // Take a copy from the array...
tmp.Set(255); // This only affects the copy
```

To change the array, you'll need to call the setter on the indexer instead. For example:

```
Color tmp = mySurface[x, y];
tmp.Set(255);
mySurface[x, y] = tmp;
```

Assuming you actually have several values in your struct, it would be simpler if you'd make your struct immutable but provide methods that returned new values, just like `DateTime.AddDays` etc. Then you could write code like:

```
mySurface[x, y] = mySurface[x, y].WithRed(255);
```

Options if you really want to avoid using a setter:

- Use `ref return` from C# 7: redefine your indexer to return a `ref Color`; although then you *can't* have a setter.
- Make `Color` a class instead of a struct
- Use a reference type *inside* `Color`, so you don't need to change the bits in the `Color` value itself. (This is really nasty - I'm not suggesting that.)

Comment: side question: new ValueTuple struct both exposes public fields and is mutable. How so? Some perfomance considerations?

Comment: You also can avoid calling setter, if you return `Color` by reference: `public ref Color this[int x, int y] => ref pixels[y, x];`.

Comment: Ended up using the ref solution.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are value types, so if you get it from the array by calling `pixels[y,x]`, you will actually create a copy of the struct to change the field on.

See also [Unable to Modify struct Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212618/unable-to-modify-struct-members)

Comment: It's not changing the property that creates the copy (not that there *is* a property in `Color`) - it's the indexer.

Comment: You are right, Jon. I didn't explain that well... I edited the answer to be more correct.